# Como a função `dplyr::n()` sabe que não está sendo chamada do ambiente global?

Tags: r, dplyr

Ao chamar a função `dplyr::n()` no ambiente global, ocorre um erro.

```
n()
# Error: This function should not be called directly
```

Esse erro faz sentido e fiquei curioso para ver como ele era implementado.

```
n
# function () 
# {
#     abort("This function should not be called directly")
# }
# <bytecode: 0x000000001650f200>
# <environment: namespace:dplyr>
```

Para minha surpresa, no entanto, não há nenhum `if` ou verificação de condição. Apenas joga o erro. O mesmo não ocorre quando chamamos `n()` no seu *habitat* natural.

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#     cyl     n
#   <dbl> <int>
# 1     4    11
# 2     6     7
# 3     8    14
```

Então as perguntas que ficam são duas:

1. Como a função `n()` sabe que está sendo chamada em outro contexto? e
2. Como a função `n()` conta? (onde está o código-fonte dessa parte)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `n` só funciona dentro do `dplyr` e faz parte de uma parte interna do pacote que é chamada de *Hybrid Evaluation*. A descrição completa [está aqui](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/internals/hybrid-evaluation.html).

*Hybrid Evaluation* é uma das principais features que faz o `dplyr` ser rápido para algumas tarefas.

A princípio, quando você faz um `summarise`, por exemplo `summarise(n = n())` o `dplyr` precisaria executar essa função para cada pedaço da base. Isso poderia ser custoso se a base tiver muitos grupos, por exemplo. Por isso o `dplyr` reconhece algumas expressões como por exemplo `n()`, `sum(variavel)` e lida com elas diretamente usando um código em C++.

No caso da função `n()` a porta de entrada para a sua definição está neste arquivo: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/inst/include/dplyr/hybrid/scalar_result/n.h#L1

Portanto, na verdade a função do R `n()` não sabe que está sendo chamada em outro contexto, na verdade, é o `dplyr` que muda o seu significado quando a função é usada dentro de um `mutate` ou `summarise`.